# Неккоректное добавление Image во Wrap Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Нужно сделать добавление миниатюр изображений на Wrap Panel из какой-то папки. Считываю названия всех изображений в определенной папке в массив строк. Написал функцию по добавлению на Wrap Panel, но она добавляет постоянно одно последнее изображение. Где я туплю, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
BitmapImage mpImg = new BitmapImage();
mpImg.BeginInit();
Image ImageName;

for (int i = 0; i < nameFiles.Length; i++)
{
    ImageName = new Image();
    mpImg.UriSource = new Uri(nameFiles[i]);
    ImageName.Width = 130;
    ImageName.Height = 100;
    ImageName.Source = mpImg;
    wrap1.Children.Add(ImageName);

}
mpImg.EndInit();
```

Comment: Спасибо.   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете один экземпляр битмапа для всех изображений, меняя ему только ссылку. Вот у вас последнее изображение и получается во всех контролах. Создавайте битмап на каждую картинку (внутри цикла).